# How to check or uncheck a checkbox with Jquery in Form 7 forms

Tags: jquery, checkbox, set, contact-form-7, checked

How can I set a checkbox in Form 7 to "checked" or "unchecked"?

The ID of the checkbox is id:brengtijdzat.

I tried:

```
$("#brengtijdzat").prop("checked", true);
```

and

```
$("#brengtijdzat").prop("checked", false);
```

but that does not work!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Old version of Jquery 
try This

```
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true); // Checks it
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', false); // Unchecks it
```

Comment: old version uses attr new version use prop

Comment: yep , that's y I ask him to use attr instead of Prop

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE SOLUTION:
I post this for anybody having these problems/questions:

This does NOT work:

```
$("#brengtijdzat").prop("checked", true);
```

This DOES work:

```
$("#brengtijdzat :input").prop("checked", true);
```

And this is a more complete WORKING code snippet:

```
if (dayNameB == "zaterdag") {
    $("#brengtijdzat").show();
    $("#brengtijdzat :input").prop("checked", true);
    $("#brengtijd").hide();
    $("#brengtijd :input").prop("checked", false);
}
```